# how to make a link contain text and shown in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

***please help me with this code***
[image]

this i a **javascript** code
not the actuall

````
var elements, searchText = "Open Help";

elements = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsBy(function (element) {
    return (element.innerHTML === searchText) ? true : false;
}, "a", document);

if (elements.length > 0) {
    //do something with elements[0]
}```
````

Comment: Please add more details about your problem, your question is not clear enough

Comment: Hi `Null Sep`, Welcome to stackoverflow! You have to read this post before asking any question.  **Post:-** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Also Java and JavaScript is **not** the same thing. If you simply don't want your form variables displayed in the URL, use a *POST* method instead of *GET* (form default method is *GET*). If you're asking how to fetch the form values after submission, then it would be easiest with a server side language such as *PHP*. Try include **ALL** relevant code, including the HTML markup, and edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you are using get method on your form.Replace that with POST method

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing and vague and I have no idea what you're trying to do, but with the input text you can just change the url with this:

`window.location.href`